# Period map for $\partial\bar\partial$-manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, hodge-theory

When we talk about the theory of variation of Hodge structures, we always assume that the central fiber is a Kähler manifold $X$, then consider a family of deformations $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$ and the period map $\mathcal P:B\to Grass(b^{p,k},H^k(X,\mathbb C))$, $b^{p,k}=dim F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)$.

What if we replace the Kähler manifold by a $\partial\bar\partial$-manifold and consider a holomorphic family of $\partial\bar\partial$-manifolds $\pi:\mathcal X\to B$?

Recall a $\partial\bar\partial$-manifold is a compact complex manifold which satisfies for any $\partial$, $\bar\partial$-closed $d$ exact $(p,q)$ form $\alpha$, there this a $(p-1,q-1)$ form $\beta$ such that $\alpha=\partial\bar\partial \beta$.

Is the theory of variation of Hodge structures remains the same? And is there also a period map $\mathcal P:B\to Grass(b^{p,k},H^k(X,\mathbb C))$?
If so, is the period map holomorphic and the Griffiths transversality still holds?

In my opinion, first we should define what $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)$ means for a non-Kähler manifold, since for a Kähler manifold, we have the Kähler identity $\Delta=2\Delta_{\bar\partial}=2\Delta_{\partial}$ from which we deduce the Hodge decomposition: $H^k(X,\mathbb C)=\oplus_{p+q=k}H^{p,q}(X)$, so we can define
$F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)=H^{p,k-p}(X)\oplus H^{p+1,k-p-1}(X)\oplus...\oplus H^{k,0}(X)$ which is obviously a subspace of $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$,
but for a non-Kähler manifold, there is no Kähler identities. But from [AT13](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-012-0406-3), we know that the Bott-Chern cohomology $H^{p,q}_{BC}(X,\mathbb C):=\frac{ker\partial\cap ker\bar\partial}{im\partial\bar\partial}$ is isomorphic to Dolbeault cohomology $H_{\bar\partial}^{p,q}(X)$ and $H_{\partial}^{p,q}(X)$, so if we define $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)=H^{p,k-p}_{BC}(X,\mathbb C)\oplus H^{p+1,k-p-1}_{BC}(X,\mathbb C)\oplus...\oplus H^{k,0}_{BC}(X,\mathbb C)$, is it reasonable to treat it as a subspace of $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$ and define a period map as in the Kähler case?

Has anyone thought it before? or any reference about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a disclaimer that I think the following facts are true, but I'm doing this over coffee and I haven't checked the details carefully. First, I'll redefine $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb{C})$ to be the space of de Rham classes represented by the sum of $(p', p'-k)$ forms with $p'\ge p$, or equivalently as
$$F^pH^k(X,\mathbb{C})= im(H^k(\Omega_X^{\ge p})\xrightarrow{\iota} H^k(X,\Omega_X^\bullet))$$
Then the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma is sufficient to guarantee the filtration is *strict* in the sense that the maps above are injective (or equivalently that the Hodge to de Rham spectral sequence degenerates); **edit** see remark 5.21 of Deligne, Griffiths, Morgan, Sullivan, *Real homotopy theory of Kähler manifolds*. Then, if I understand the notation of the paper you linked, this should probably give decomposition in terms of BC cohomology as you wrote. The other thing I want to remark is that if $\mathcal{X}\to B$ is a smooth proper family such that the fibres satisfy $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma, then usual arguments should imply that
$$F^p R^kf_*\Omega_{\mathcal{X}/B}^\bullet= im(R^kf_*\Omega_{\mathcal{X}/B}^{\ge p}\xrightarrow{\iota}R^kf_*\Omega_{\mathcal{X}/B}^\bullet) $$
satisfies Griffiths transversality etc. So in this sense, things work. However, you would be  missing the polarization, which need for most of the deeper results about the Griffiths period map.

Comment: Do you mean you define $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)=ker(d:F^pA^k\to F^{p+1}A^k)/im(d:F^{p-1}A^k\to F^pA^k)$?

Comment: Almost, but  there is no shift because $d(F^p)\subset F^p$

Comment: Sorry that I made a mistake, I mean $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)=ker(d:F^pA^k\to F^pA^{k+1})/im(d:F^pA^{k-1}\to F^pA^k)$. If we define the filtration like this, I don't think it obvious that we will have of decompostion of this filtration in BC cohomology, since for the Kahler case, it takes p158-159 for Voisin in her book<Hodge theory and...> to prove the corresponding decomposition.

Comment: Voisin's argument  assumes the  Kahler condition, so it won't work here. But see the ref. in the edited version.

Comment: Remark 5.21 says that a manifols satisfies the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma is equivalent to (a)+(b), (a) is the Frolicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$ and (b) is the filtration on $H^k(X,\mathbb C)$ gives a Hodge structure of weitht $k$, so you mean (b) implies that $F^pH^k(X,\mathbb C)$ in the above definition can be decomposited to a sum of BC cohomologies?

Comment: Technically, it gives an isomorphism $F^pH^k(X)= H^{p,k-p}\oplus\ldots$ with Dolbeault cohomology. Now use the fact, you stated, that BC and Dolbeault cohomologies are isomorphic.